# TorBrowser on macOS High Sierra playback issue

Tags: firefox, mac

I'm experiencing video/audio playback issues on the actual version of TorBrowser installed on macOS High Sierra.

I think it's about HLS.js library:
https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/

It seems that Firefox 52.4.1 resolve this issue.
But the current version is 52.4.0
See: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/1369

Any news on the next TorBrowser update?

Thanks

Comment: Has this been resolved now? 7.0.7 said it fixed: "Bug 23807: Tab crashes when playing video on High Sierra"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to TorBrowser version 7.0.7 (and 7.5a6) resolve the problem, because they come with Firefox 52.4.1

m.